# Identify when Windows 8 Style (Metro) application is in background or lost focus

Tags: c#, focus, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've got a game that I want to pause whenever the user moves to another application.  For example, when the charms menu is selected, the user presses the windows key, alt-tab to another application, click on another application or anything else that would make the application lose focus.

Of course this should be trivial!  I only have a `Page` and a `Canvas` and I've tried `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events on the `Canvas`, but they don't fire.

The closest I've come is using `PointerCaptureLost` on `CoreWindow` after capturing the pointer.  This works for application switching when the charms menu is selected, but this does not work when the windows key is pressed.

**EDIT:**

With the help of Chris Bowen below, the final 'solution' is the following:

```
public MainPage() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CapturePointer();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCaptureLost += PointerCaptureLost;
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += PointerPressed;
    Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += VisibilityChanged;
}

private void VisibilityChanged(object sender, VisibilityChangedEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Visible) {
        CapturePointer();
    }
    else {
        Pause();
    }
}

void PointerPressed(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args) {
    CapturePointer();
}

private void CapturePointer() {
    if(hasCapture == false) {
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.SetPointerCapture();
        hasCapture = true;
    }
}

void PointerCaptureLost(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args) {
    hasCapture = false;
    Pause();
}

private bool hasCapture;
```

It still seems that their *should* be an easier way, so please let me know if you find something more elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the [Window.VisibilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.visibilitychanged.aspx) event. Something like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += Current_VisibilityChanged;
}

void Current_VisibilityChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.VisibilityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Visible) 
    {
        //Something useful
    }
}
```

Though it won't catch Charms activation, it should work for the other cases you mentioned.

Comment: Shazam.  That's a beauty of a little trick, I've never seen that before.  It fills in the cases that I was missing nicely.  I'll put the complete implementation in an edit above.

Comment: Isn't this keep attaching event to Static variable every time you access this page? So handler will be called multiple times for multi access?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `onSuspending` event predefined in the App.xaml.cs to handle the pausing of your game. The event fires whenever the application is suspended, so it could work. You may have to do checks to e.g. make sure the game is actually running to start with before you try to pause it though, because this event fires when any page in the app is being suspended.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't execute on any of the events that I listed.  Also, it takes about 5 seconds from the time the application is closed to fire.  I remember from a TechEd session that this is in case the user re-opens it quickly.  I need something that I can catch within a single frame (i.e. 1/60th sec).